# Get False item from python list of dict?

Tags: python, optimization, sum, list-comprehension

I have list of python dicts based on class which contains field status. How to "sum" number of items == False? My approach is to check size of list then subtract sum of items == True from list. It works, but is it possible to sum False elements at once (list.count(False))?

Code which works fine:

```
def get_errors(self):
    return len(self.container) - sum(item['status'] for item in self.container)
```

How to bypass subtract? Something:

```
sum(item['status'] for item in self.container if not item)    # if item == False
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just count them. Add 1 for every false item

```
 sum(1 for item in self.container if item['status']==False)
```

Or, you could do the complementary of what you're doing

```
 sum(not item['status'] for item in self.container)
```

Comment: or `len(item in self.container if item['status']==False)`

Comment: @Anonymousmiliana: good one too. we could make a list of all possible ways